$V$ Euclidean iff there exist linear isometry that $f(v)=w$ for $|v|=|w|$
From the book 'a course in metric geometry' exercise 1.2.24 : 
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional normed space. prove that V is Euclidean iff for any tow vectors $v,w\in V$ such that $|v|=|w|$ there exists a linear isometry $f:V\rightarrow V$ such that $f(v)=w$ 
my try for $\rightarrow$: intuition says the function should be a rotation but I have struggles making one. For an orthonormal frame $\{a_i\}$ I can write $v=\sum v_ia_i$ I must find another orthonormal frame $\{b_i\}$ that satisfies $w=\sum v_ib_i$ and define a linear $f$ that $f(a_i)=b_i$. As inner product is continuous by Intermediate value theorem there exists a vector that satisfies $\langle w,b_1\rangle=v_1$ and then considering $\langle w-v_1b_1,b_2\rangle = v_2$ but can't show they are orthogonal

Can you define Euclidean?

@CameronWilliams Euclidean space is a vector space with a scalar product on it

Suppose $V$ is euclidean and let $v,w\in V$ unitary, if $v\in\{\pm w\}$ you can take $f=\pm{\rm id}$. In the other case, the family $(v,w)$ is free so you can complete it to form a unitary orthogonal basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ of $V$, with $e_1=v$ and $e_2=w$. Define $f:V\to V$ by $f(e_1)=e_2,f(e_2)=e_1$ and $f(e_i)=e_i$ for $i>2$, then $f$ is an isometry and $f(v)=w$. Now suppose that the orthogonal group $\mathcal{O}(V)$ acts transitively on the sphere $\mathbf{S}_V$ of $V$. Since $\mathcal{O}(V)$ is a compact group it admits an Haar measure, we can thus define
$$ \langle v,w\rangle=\int_{\mathcal{O}(V)}\langle g(v), g(w)\rangle_V dg $$
for any fixed inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_V$ on $V$. By construction the norm $\|\cdot\|$ associated to $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is invariant by the action of $\mathcal{O}(V)$, that is $\|f(v)\|=\|v\|$ for all isometry $f$ and all $v\in V$. Since $\mathcal{O}(V)$ acts transitively on $\mathbf{S}_V$, this means that $\|\cdot\|$ is constant on $\mathbf{S}_V$, we thus get that
$$ \forall v\in V,\|v\|=|v|\left\|\frac{v}{|v|}\right\|=\alpha|v| $$
where $\alpha>0$ is the value of $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbf{S}_V$. Finally,
$$ \forall v,w\in V,\frac{1}{2}\left(|v+w|^2-|v|^2-|w|^2\right)=\frac{1}{2\alpha^2}\left(\|v+w\|^2-\|v\|^2-\|w\|^2\right)=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\langle v,w\rangle $$
and the norm $|\cdot|$ is induced by the inner product $\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.

thank you but I don't know much about group theory, what book do you suggest to read in order to understand the proof you have written for the $\leftarrow$
